# Which is more prefered to be called, "XSL file" or "XSLT file"?

Tags: xslt

What should I call my file containing XSL code (XSLT code?),

which one sounds more sensible/meaningful.

I know the abbreviation of both of them. But don't know which one to use and where ..

---

I just now came across these words in w3schools.com

> It started with XSL and ended up with
>   XSLT, XPath, and XSL-FO.

and also saw written "XSL Source code", So what about .. Alejandro's comments .. ?

Now my question reduces to yet more simple version..

Can we call XSLT code as XSL code too? or is it deprecated?

Comment: @who_ever, I can see a "vote to close", please concern to write a reason, I am ready to vote too, if you are up with valid reason, thanks regards.

Comment: Good and interesting question, as always (+1). :)

Comment: @infant programmer: what do you mean by "XSL code"? XSL is a lenguage family.

Comment: @Alejandro, Corrections are awaited :) that is what my question is, I have much domination on XSLT although, but at this point am confused.

Comment: @infant programmer: w3schools is a good site but I don't think that it has better formality than specifications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Introduction

> A transformation expressed in XSLT is
>   called a stylesheet

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#what-is-xslt

> [Definition: A transformation in the
>   XSLT language is expressed in the form
>   of a stylesheet, whose syntax is
>   well-formed XML [XML 1.0] conforming
>   to the Namespaces in XML
>   Recommendation [Namespaces in XML
>   1.0].]

Leaving aside the formality of the specification, you can call it what you will. With respect to the components of the stylesheet (or transformation): for XSLT 1.0 they are `instructions` and its contents are `templates`, for XSLT 2.0 they are `declarations` and `instructions` and its contents are `sequence constructors`

Comment: @infant programmer: You are wellcome! Ask any time.

Answer (score 3):

To be nitpicker, I believe XSL is the language and XSLT is a transformation (a piece of code that is written in XSL to transform one XML to another).

So when you're talking of particular pieces of code I think XSLT is more appropriate (just XSLT not XSLT codes), like apha XSLT or so. But when you are talking about language, it should be XSL e.g. XSL skills, XSL code.

Comment: this is wrong. Extensible Stylesheet Language Family (XSL) [http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/] has three parts: XSLT ("a language for transforming"), XSL-FO ("an XML vocabulary for specifying formatting semantics") and a XML core expression language XPath.

Comment: @Alegandro, thanks for the comments, notable ones, would like to see the discussion and come to conclusion. thanks regards.

Comment: @Alejandro. Right, noted. 

Given that, the transformations that we write are XSLT more specifically. Although, people often use word XSL to represent them.

Is it a fair conclusion?

Comment: I think that you could use the word XSL, but if you are reference a particular transformation and not the language family this could make some confused. Think about XSL like an abstraction, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not only a matter of opinion**: just look and see how many questions are in the [**xslt**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt) tag (2299) and how many are in [**xsl**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xsl) (753) -- the result is clear, isn't it? :)

Related to this in 2010 I proposed that the `xsl` tag be considered a synonim for the `xslt` tag. This proposal was voted and approved.

Comment: so what is the conclusion? please include it, Alejandro's comments are notable too. regards.

Comment: rather I am confused after reading Alejandro's comments. I need some clarification. :)

Comment: How do I vote for the proposal? Or has it been accepted meanwhile?

Comment: @0xA3, Goto that page, end of the statements. you can see xsl and xslt-2 having couple of uv and dv corresponding to each of them. once you vote them they disappear.

Comment: @infant programmer: Sorry, I don't see any of that.

Comment: @0xA3: When there was voting allowed, there were two candidate-synonims on this page: xsl and xslt-2.0. Now I see only xsl -- this is probably why there is no voting anymore -- seems xsl has won over xslt-2.0. Don't ask me whether all this has any meaning -- obviously they are still experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

There is no appreciable difference. I use them interchangeably, and so do most people.

Answer (score 0):

Really, does it matter? I'm all for correct terminology, because it usually matters in IT, but in this case you really won't confuse anyone whichever one you use.

Comment: thanks for the response, I have to communicate heavily to my clients, they may or may not be having knowledge on this, I chose to use proper terminology than going blind, Regards :)